# what does row[12] mean when used as a condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a delivered script that I'm having trouble understanding.

```
if (!row[20] || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

I need to know... what does `row[20]` or `!row[20]` mean?  I know that they reference a column yes... but is it meaning something like "not blank" for `!row[20]`?

And how can I specify something like:

```
if ((!row[20] && row[12]=TRUE) || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, boolean type is judged by "if".

"!row[20]" means that it isn't empty. Namely, it's "false". So "row[20]" means that it has a data. Namely, it's "true". "rowHasChanged" means "true". "||" and "&&" mean "or" and  "and" of the logical operators, respectively.

```
if (!row[20] || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

By knowing all patterns of "true" of "false", I think that you can understand about this script. So it investigated the condition of "row[20]" and "rowHasChanged" for this script. A script used to investigate is as follows.

**Sample script 1 :**

```
var bol = [true, false];
var row = [];
for (i in bol) {
  row[20] = bol[i];
  for (j in bol) {
    var rowHasChanged = bol[j];
    if (!row[20] || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
      Logger.log("EXECUTED. ( row[20] = %s, rowHasChanged = %s )", row[20], rowHasChanged)
    } else {
      Logger.log("Not executed. ( row[20] = %s, rowHasChanged = %s )", row[20], rowHasChanged)
    }
  }    
}
```

**Result :**

```
EXECUTED. ( row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = true )
EXECUTED. ( row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = true )
EXECUTED. ( row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = false )
Not executed. ( row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = false )
```

When "rowHasChanged" is "true" under irrespective of "row[20]", the commands in "if" are executed. When "rowHasChanged" is "false", only when "row[20]" is false, the commands in "if" are executed.

About next script,

```
if ((!row[20] && row[12]=TRUE) || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

For this script, I think that an error will occur. If you want to use this, change to

```
if ((!row[20] && row[12] == true) || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

or

```
if ((!row[20] && row[12]) || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
```

As mentioned above, also it investigated for this script.

**Sample script 2 :**

```
var bol = [true, false];
var row = [];
for (i in bol) {
  row[20] = bol[i];
  for (j in bol) {
    row[12] = bol[j];
    for (k in bol) {
      var rowHasChanged = bol[k];
      if ((!row[20] && row[12]) || (row[20] && rowHasChanged )) {
        Logger.log("EXECUTED. ( row[12] = %s, row[20] = %s, rowHasChanged = %s )", row[12], row[20], rowHasChanged)
      } else {
        Logger.log("Not executed. ( row[12] = %s, row[20] = %s, rowHasChanged = %s )", row[12], row[20], rowHasChanged)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result :**

```
EXECUTED. ( row[12] = true, row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = true )
EXECUTED. ( row[12] = true, row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = false )
EXECUTED. ( row[12] = false, row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = true )
EXECUTED. ( row[12] = true, row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = true )
Not executed. ( row[12] = true, row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = false )
Not executed. ( row[12] = false, row[20] = true, rowHasChanged = false )
Not executed. ( row[12] = false, row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = true )
Not executed. ( row[12] = false, row[20] = false, rowHasChanged = false )
```

If this will be helpful for you, I'm glad.